# How to make an Ajax call and grab certain classes from an internal Jquery Mobile page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, pagination, html-table

I have a table on a Jquery Mobile site. On loading the page I grab the table rows and create a single or multiple subpages each holding a certain number of rows (0-100,101-200,201-300 and so on).

So I end up with a DOM like this:

```html
 // main page
 <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
   <table>
     <tbody class="tableRowDropZone">
       // empty body
     </tbody>
   <table>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="rows0-100">
    // table rows 0-100
</div>
...
```

I now wanted to use the experimental JQM fetchlink plugin to load in rows as needed, so I could easily set up a pagination or endless table widget.

Fetchlink uses three data-attributes to be specified on a link:
    **data-target** = where to put the fetched content
    **data-method** = replace,append,...
    **data-fragment** = what piece of content to load, any jquery selector

This works fine as long as the page I'm calling in is not inside the DOM already. The problem is once the subpage is inside the DOM, and I ajax call something like this:

```html
<a href="#rows0-100" data-method="replace" data-fragment="tr.rows0-100" data-target=".tableRowDropZone">grab rows</a>
```

the **data-fragment** attribute doesn't play along and my fragment to search for is an empty []. Here is the part in question from fetchlink:

```js
       ...
       // fragment is assigned
       fragment    = self.jqmData( "fragment" ), 
       load     = fragment || ":jqmData(role='page')",           

       targetEl.ajaxStart(function(){
           var $el = $(this);
           $.get( url, function( resp ) {                    
                var rscript = /<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi;
                // wrap response in a div and find load 
                // THIS TURNS UP NOTHING on internal pages, because load = []
                var data = $( $("<div/>").append( resp.replace( rscript, "" ) ).find( load ) ),
```

**My problem:**
For internal pages data-fragment does not seem to take any jquery selector. If I call **TR**, this returns all rows (0-300), but if I call **TR.rows0-100** (each row gets a class like this) the load fragment is empty.

I have consoled this for an afternoon now... if I console:

```js
 console.log( $( $("<div/>").append( resp.replace( rscript, "" ) ).find( "div" ) ) );
```

I'm getting all divs like this *div#mainpage*. If I feed this into the data-fragment, it works. However consoling my table rows:

```js
 console.log( $( $("<div/>").append( resp.replace( rscript, "" ) ).find( "tr") ) );
```

returns this *[tr,tr,tr,tr...]*, so I think I understand why **TR.rows0-100** doesn't work (*tr* does not match *tr.rows0-100*. But I don't know what to do about it...

**Question:**
Can anyone tell me what I need to do, in order to be able to use regular jquery selectors on the data-fragment attribute or at least get my rows to load if I specify them by tr.class?

**EDIT:**
it seems I can only select classes which are hard coded into the HTML. So if I add a class of .dummy to all table wors I can grab tr.dummy allright. However if I add another class by jQuery like .rows0-100 I cannot grab tr.rows0-100.

**EDIT-2:**
Looking at the response = resp, I think I know what's wrong. Of course the response only returns the plain HTML, so any classes I'm dynamically adding on the page are not inside the ajax-response. So does this mean the only thing I can do is iterate through all table rows and tr:eq(my from_row) to tr:eq(to_row)? there must be a better way.